# Stored procedure date parameter filters - Ignore if Null

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am using the following SQL in my stored procedure to not filter by date parameters if they are null.

```
WHERE (Allocated >= ISNULL(@allocatedStartDate, '01/01/1900') 
       AND Allocated <= ISNULL(@allocatedEndDate,'01/01/3000'))
AND
(MatterOpened >= ISNULL(@matterOpenedStartDate, '01/01/1900') 
 AND MatterOpened <= ISNULL(@matterOpenedEndDate, '01/01/3000'))
```

Will this give any kind of performance hit when dealing with a lot of records?

Is there a better way to do this?

Number of records - around 500k

Comment: You probably wanted to put `MatterOpened` (instead of `Allocated`) in that very last line of your query - right??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or just let the query optimizer have it:

```
WHERE ( @allocatedStartDate is NULL or Allocated >= allocatedStartDate ) and
   ( @allocatedEndDate is NULL or Allocated <= @allocatedEndDate ) and
   ( @matterOpenedStartDate is NULL or MatterOpened >= @matterOpenedStartDate ) and
   ( @matterOpenedEndDate is NULL or MatterOpened <= @matterOpenedEndDate )
```

Note that this is not logically equivalent to your query.  The last line uses column MatterOpened, not Allocated, as I assume that was a typographic error.

If performance is really an issue, you may want to consider adding indexes and changing the stored procedure to execute different queries based on the parameters.  At least break it into: no filter, filter only on Allocated, filter only on MatterOpened, filter on both columns.

Comment: It's a matter of preference, I suppose, but completely different queries based on the parameters can mean a lot of redundant code and extra maintenance when making changes. I don't like dynamic SQL's "sea of red" but if you can read that cleanly I'd rather make one change than four (or more; we don't know that these are the only parameters)...

Comment: @AaronBertrand - Agreed.  If one knows that 82%* of the calls perform no filtering then it may make sense to have a simple `IF` that chooses between an unfiltered and a fully filtered query.  Another possibilty is to use `WITH RECOMPILE` to optimize each query based on the parameters.  One needs to analyze the workload and environment to make an informed decision.  (Coincidentally, 82% of all statistics are made up on the spot.)

Answer (score 1):

In a lot of cases, dynamic SQL can be better for you instead of trying to rely on the optimizer to cache a good plan for both NULL and non-NULL parameters.

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @sql = N'SELECT 
... 
WHERE 1 = 1';

SET @sql = @sql + CASE WHEN @allocatedStartDate IS NOT NULL THEN 
    ' AND Allocated >= ''' + CONVERT(CHAR(8), @allocatedStartDate, 112) + '''';

-- repeat for other clauses

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

No, it's not fun to maintain, but each variation should get its own plan in the cache. You'll want to test with different settings for "Optimize for ad hoc workloads" and database-level paramaterization settings. Oops, just noticed 2005. Keep those in mind for the future (and any readers who aren't still stuck on 2005).

Also make sure to use `EXEC sp_executesql` and not `EXEC`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of checking to see if the variable is null in your query, check them at the beginning of your stored procedure and change the value to your default

```
SELECT
   @allocatedStartDate = ISNULL(@allocatedStartDate, '01/01/1900'),
   @allocatedEndDate = ISNULL(@allocatedEndDate,'01/01/3000'),
   @matterOpenedStartDate = ISNULL(@matterOpenedStartDate, '01/01/1900'),
   @matterOpenedEndDate = ISNULL(@matterOpenedEndDate, '01/01/3000')
```

Comment: Also to avoid parameter sniffing issues you may want to test by creating separate local variables, passing the parameter values to them, and using the local variables in the query. Or vice versa. Parameter sniffing can be bad when the first compilation is based on atypical parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
DECLARE @allocatedStartDate DATETIME=GETDATE()
DECLARE @allocatedEndDate DATETIME=GETDATE()-2

;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT 
        ISNULL(@allocatedStartDate, '01/01/1900') AS allocatedStartDate,
        ISNULL(@allocatedEndDate,'01/01/3000') AS allocatedEndDate 
)
SELECT
    *
FROM
    YourTable
    CROSS JOIN CTE
WHERE (Allocated >= CTE.allocatedStartDate 
       AND Allocated <= CTE.allocatedEndDate)
AND
(MatterOpened >= CTE.allocatedStartDate 
 AND Allocated <= CTE.allocatedEndDate)
```